# How to concatenate strings from one list to other strings in the second list in Python?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists in Python:

First list contains sentences and the second one contains uncommon words from the sentences in the first list

```
sentences = ['Buy apples', 'red apples', 'green']
uncommon_words = ['buy', 'red', 'green', 'apples']
```

How can i get a new list with uncommon words added in the end of the sentences which are not present in the sentence?
 *(preferably with added **' - '** at the beginning of those words)*

**Example:**

```
new_list = ['Buy apples -red -green', 'red apples -buy -green', 'green -buy -red -apples']
```

Comment: do you need case insensitive answer? (you have "Buy" and "buy")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
sentences = ['Buy apples', 'red apples', 'green']
uncommon_words = ['buy', 'red', 'green', 'apples']
new_list = []
for i in sentences:
    new_list.append("{} {}".format(i, " ".join("-"+j for j in uncommon_words if j.lower() not in i.lower())))
print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['Buy apples -red -green', 'red apples -buy -green', 'green -buy -red -apples']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
res = []
for sent in sentences:
    res.append(sent)
    for word in uncommon_words:
        if word not in sent:
            res[-1]+=f" -{word}"
```

Output:

```
['buy apples -red -green', 'red apples -buy -green', 'green -buy -red -apples']
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
lower_c_s = [a.lower() for a in sentences]
new_list = [s + ' -{}'.format(unc) for s in sentences for unc in uncommon_words if unc.lower() not in lower_c_s]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can take the uncommon words in any order, you can use `set` and utilize set's `difference`:

```
sentences = ['Buy apples', 'red apples', 'green']
uncommon_words = ['buy', 'red', 'green', 'apples']

print([x + ' -' + ' -'.join(set(uncommon_words).difference(set(map(lambda x: x.lower(), x.split())))) for x in sentences])

# ['Buy apples -red -green', 'red apples -green -buy', 'green -red -apples -buy']
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

`new_sentences = [] 
 # For each sentence in sentences
 for sent in sentences:
     l = sent.lower().split(' ')
     # For each word in uncommon words
     for word in uncommon_words:
         # Check if uncommon word is not in sentence
         if word not in l:
             # If not present, update the sentence
             sent = sent +' -' + word
     # Add sentence to new sentences
     new_sentences.append(sent)
 print(new_sentences)`